# Abort observable subscription sequence in Angular 2

Tags: http, angular, observable, subscribe

I'm trying to create an 'interceptor' for AuthHttp service (angular2-jwt). I created a class that extends AuthHttp and use that instead. So far it seems to work fine. What I want to do now is, if the server responds with a 401 code is to force a logout within my app and ignore following subscriptions (I'm not sure if these subscriptions are executed sequentially so I don't know if what I'm gonna ask is possible).

As I just want to show an error in this scenario, I just need from this subscription to abort the queue and ignore further subscriptions. Here's the code I got so far for the get method:

```
get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    let observable = super.get(url, options);
    observable.subscribe(
        () => { },
        (error: Response) => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                // Logout and ignore all other subscriptions
            }
        }
    );

    return observable;
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can [unsubscribe](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html#instance-method-unsubscribe). The `subscribe` method returns a `Subscription` object. You can use that to unsubscribe:

```
get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    let observable = super.get(url, options);
    let subscription = observable.subscribe(
        () => { },
        (error: Response) => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                // Logout and ignore all other subscriptions
                subscription.unsubscribe(); 
            }
        }
    );

    return observable;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I dont understand what I would accomplish with this. As a test I pasted your code and put a console.log with 'unsubscribe'. In another subscribe (in a service that calls a rest api using .get() and subscribes to the observable) I wrote another console.log with another string. Both of these got printed to the console. What I want to avoid is that no other error handlers of this observable get executed.

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you please try to explain the issue a little better?

Comment: I have set up an APP that requires login against a REST API. On log in, the app is issued a jwt token that it stores and uses to validate all secured api calls (with AuthHttp). When retrieving data, I use a post or get call and subscribe to retrieve it or show an error (couldn't connect or the such). If the server can't validate a call it returns a 401. What I want is to attach a function (as an interceptor) to check every authenticated call and if the server returns a 401 force a logout and skip all other errors checks it may have subscribed if possible.

Comment: Oh. That will be a bit harder. You might want to keep references to all of your subscriptions (in a service), and unsubscribe from all of them once you get the 401.